# Unable to set global unicast address in Server client program using Qt

Tags: qt, networking, ipv6, ethernet

I'm new to IPv6 and I'll explain my issue in detail.
Using Qt I have developed the Server Client program using Qt.

->I used local link address in both server and client.

->And the ip address changes from terminal to terminal, if I run server from 3 terminals server IP address is different from three terminals and client has different ip addresses.

->I want to discover exact/current server address from client program to connect with server at run time.

How can I do that, please suggest.

And the second issue is, on changing from Local link to Global unicast address might ip -6 neigh show will work because global link will expose all over the network.

In this case I'm trying to change the below code:
Previous code: *QHostAddress address = QHostAddress::AnyIPv6;* server starts and stay in listening state.

Manually assigning the Global Unicast address with below code.
   *QHostAddress address;
   address.setAddress("2001:0DB8:0000:0002:0022:2217:FF3B:118C");*
This time server not started, saying address is not available.

Please suggest in this regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For discovering connected servers, you could send UDP datagrams to `ff02::1`. This is a multicast address that will reach every connected IPv6 device on the link (link-local scope). Of course that means that the servers needs to listen for those datagrams.

The [Simple Service Discovery Protocol (SSDP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol) uses this kind of approach.

For your server problem, it would have been nice to have some more code.

Assuming you did something similar to that:

```
QHostAddress address;
address.setAddress("2001:0DB8:0000:0002:0022:2217:FF3B:118C");
QTcpServer server;
server.listen(address)
```

It means that you listen on `2001:0DB8:0000:0002:0022:2217:FF3B:118C` and therefore this address should be assigned to one of your interface (network card).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. to the second Qs the code you provided I'm doing in the same way but when I try to connect from client with the same IP address its not connecting, let me know do I need to configure anything to make use of Global Unicast address??  And about the discover the ip address can you please provide me the sample code to discover the IP Address, and let me know this discovery method can discover link local address?

Comment: You shouldn't need to configure anything specific, can you provide more info ? Like how the PC are physically connected, if you can ping one PC from the other, what are the config of your network cards and some more code, in particular the code where you configure the socket.

Comment: @krishna It seems you do not quite understand how IP networking works. You do not discover addresses directly. You send a multicast packet, some network nodes will hopefully catch it and respond. What you discover is the responses which will give you IP addresses, those addresses beeing whatever address the responding nodes choose to put in their responses. Also, I will not provide sample code for this, this is the bases of UPD: open a socket and listen on one machine and open a socket and send data on the other machine. This is fairly documented in QUdpSocket doc.

Comment: I'm able to connect server and client with static and local link IP Address, i.e IPv6 local link address generated from one terminal is: FE80::42:AFF:FE42:2002, from the second terminal I'm running the client by giving this static ip address as code below  _QString ip="FE80::42:AFF:FE42:2002%eth0";
   Socket->connectToHostEncrypted(ip, 1200, domainName.localDomainName());_ which works perfectly. Now my issue is I want to find out/Discover the server IP address dynamically, How can I do that, this is my main issue.

Comment: @krishna And this is covered by the answer I gave.

Comment: I'm new to network programming, I'm finding out the solutions, please help me in this regards.

Comment: And the other problem I have is with using global unicast address, I have read something like local link will be local to the networks and to make server to listen globally use global unicast and when I provide give the address manually it is just saying server Address is not available, my mail id krishnasanthosh.n@gmail.com please help what should I do make the server to global.

Comment: @krishna I cannot help you if you do not have a more specific question. If you are really new to network programming, you should start by reading websites about IP, TCP and UDP to have a basic understanding of it. Also Qt documentation of its network classes have extensive exemples (with code) of what you can do. Once you have done that, you can come back to stack overflow and either complete this question (by editing it) or ask a new question. Either way you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion I really accepting that. my issue is  I want to find the ipv6 address of server from client dynamically, as you said I have to send UDP broadcast Message from client to server, so that server will respond back to client with server ip address is my understanding correct? and my code is totally mixed up with all the communication, I'll try to make a separate code for that n then I'll share with you. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer after referring to few topics and sites:
To the brief my issue is: I need to find the Server Host address dynamically from client.
So I found something on broadcast UDP datagram message through out the network will receive to all nodes in the network and listening nodes will response back to the clients with host address and port.

So firstly I tried by sending broadcast message(only in IPv4 which is not available in IPv6) that is successful.

In IPv6 broadcast will do turned to MultiCast, to make use of multicast 
from the client have to bind the multicast addres "ff02::1%eth0" then from server have to joinmulticast group "ff02::1%eth0"

This will successfully helps in discovery the network which are in the same network.

Please correct me if there is any wrong, and let me know your suggestions to make my code even better.

--Krishna.

Comment: Using broadcast in IPv4 or the all hosts multicast in IPv6 for this is a misuse of either of those. You only use them if you want to interrupt _every_ host on a LAN because that is what happens. Since you are only interested in a subset of the hosts on a LAN, you should multicast to a specific multicast group to which the interested hosts subscribe. That will only interrupt the interested hosts. It seems pretty arrogant that you would decide to interrupt hosts that have no interest in your traffic, and many companies will reject your application for doing that.

Comment: Good to know this information, my scenario is I have two devices and I want to communicate through Ethernet IPv6, whenever client device is connected client need to find out the server address dynamically. so I multicast all hosts. Yes as you said there might be few hosts which are not interested. I'll definitely take your suggestions and will find the way to connect with specific multicast group. Let me know how can I do that  it would help me or guide me for better understanding.